# .vbs: write protection for header/footer in Word

Tags: vbscript, ms-word

I am currently working on some visual basic scripts (.vbs) for word. I need to find out whether the header/footer is write protected or not. I used following snippet:

```
Sub main(testAction)

Dim doc 'As Word.Document
Dim paAction 'As Engine.clsParamAction
Dim sAction 'As String
Dim paDocument 'As Engine.clsParamAction
Dim sDocumentName 'As String
Dim paValue 'As Engine.clsParamAction

Set paDocument = testAction.paramAction("Document Name", True)
If paDocument Is Nothing Then
    sDocumentName = "#1"
else
    sDocumentName = paDocument.inputView.Value
End If
Set doc = WaitForDocument(sDocumentName , lTimeout)

Set paAction = testAction.paramAction("Action", True)   
sAction = paAction.inputView.value

Set paValue = testAction.paramAction("Value", True)  
select case (lcase(sAction))
    case "headersectionisprotected":
        paValue.actValue = doc.Sections(1).Headers(2).Range.Sections.Item(1).ProtectedForForms
        paValue.HandleActValue
        Exit Sub    
end select
End Sub
```

The subroutine is called via Tricentis Tosca - I am sorry I am not able to give a reproducible "standalone" example:

[image: Subroutine integrated to Tricentis Tosca]

Obviously the command "doc.Sections(1).Headers(2).Range.Sections.Item(1).ProtectedForForms" does not work as expected - the return value is always true, no matter if the header is protected or not.
Note: Tosca is not making the troubles here because I have several other subs integrated like that and all of them are working fine.

Comment: Are you talking about VBScript or VBA? This is not the same and it is not clear from your question. Also please see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613). Try to [edit] and improve your question that can be answered according [ask]. Note that things like "*But I get an error"* are pretty useless for someone reading the question as we need to know which error message exactly you get and in which line. Please try to provide a [mcve].

Comment: *"return code is always `true`"* Which return code is true? How is the sub `main` called? What is `testAction`? Because the code you show is no [mcve] you probably need to explain more about that code. When you ask *"What's wrong in the command?"* my first question is which command do you mean?

Comment: *I am sorry I am not able to give a reproducible "standalone" example* Why not? I don't see a reason why you wouldn't be able to make a standalone example that isolates the problem. Since you seem to be sure it isn't caused by the 3th party tool, the problem should be there when called directly in VBA shouldn't it?